# Class<T extends AnotherClass> methods generics

Tags: java, generics, inheritance, casting, abstraction

I have this class

```
public class ClusterMapPresenter<T extends ClusterItem>{

    private ClusterMapView<T> clusterMapView;

    public ClusterMapPresenter(ClusterMapView<T> clusterMapView){
        this.clusterMapView = clusterMapView;
    }

    public void createView() {
        setItems(getMockItems());
    }

    private List<T> getMockItems() {
        List<T> items = new ArrayList<>();
        items.add( new SpeditionClusterItem(new Spedition(Constants.MOCK)));
        return items;
    }   

    public void setItems(List<T> clusterItems){
        clusterMapView.setMarkers(clusterItems);
    }
}
```

Where `SpeditionClusterItem` implements `ClusterItem`.

I only managed to make it work by adding the casting to T to

```
items.add((T)new SpeditionClusterItem(new Spedition(Constants.MOCK)));
```

However I don't really like this approach, is there a better way to design this class?

I'll add the next pieces of code:

```
public interface ClusterMapView<T extends ClusterItem> extends BaseView {
    public void setMarkers(List<T> markers);

}
```

This interface is implemented in the follow activity:

```
public class Activity implements ClusterMapView<SpeditionClusterItem> {

    private ClusterMapPresenter<SpeditionClusterItem> mClusterMapPresenter;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
...
        mClusterMapPresenter = new ClusterMapPresenter<>(this);
...        
    }


    @Override
    public void setMarkers(List<SpeditionClusterItem> markers) {
        mMapFragment.addItemsToMap(markers);

    }

}
```

The point is, I want the activity to show the method with the parameter set in the implementation.

Comment: What if you created `new ClusterMapPresenter<OtherClusterItemImpl>().getMockItems()`? The returned list would appear as `List<OtherClusterItemImpl>` but would contain `SpeditionClusterItem` values.

Comment: This is not how generics are used. Inside `ClusterMapPresenter`, you do not know what the type of `T` is, but your code makes assumptions about it. If you more clearly explain why you are trying to do this, we may be able to suggest an alternative. There may be no reason to use generics to begin with.

Comment: The point is i'm currently using it with in the Activity with new `ClusterMapPresenter<SpeditionClusterItem>(this)` and I'd like to show the resulting method as List<SpeditionClusterItem> (that's why i'd like to use generics)

Comment: I'll post more code snippets.

Comment: If you know the resulting `List` should always be `List<SpeditionClusterItem>`, why do you think you need generics? Posting more code *might* be helpful, but again, please also more clearly explain *what you are trying to do and why*.

Comment: In this project probably yes, but I'm trying to write a reusable generic version so the resulting list would be List<ObjectSetInTheImplementation>

Comment: By the way, shouldn't the compiler know that `T extends ClusterItem`?

Comment: The compiler does know that T extends ClusterItem. But it could be any sub class of ClusterItem. Which is what the earlier comments tried to point out. SpeditionClusterItem is just the one of many possible sub classes of ClusterItem, the compiler cannot guarantee type safety and that's why it needs a cast.

Comment: Great, I got it. I solved the issue by delegating the object retrieval to another class. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I kind of resolved it by separating the list retrieval from the presenter, adding the list in the constructor.

```
public ClusterMapPresenter(ClusterMapView<T> clusterMapView, List<T> clusterItems){
        this.clusterMapView = clusterMapView;
        this.clusterItems = clusterItems;
    }
```

I am not really sure this is good design, but it works. Any suggestion on how to improve it are welcome.